# display:inline-table

Tags: css, inline, displaytag

IE 7 not supporting `display:inline-table` ?

Other browsers supports. What should I do for the alternate solution?

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the inline-table display property? If you describe it perhaps someone could suggest a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox and IE8 support `display:inline-table;`. IE6 supports `display:inline;`

```
<style>.inline_table {display:inline-table;*display:inline;}</style>
<table class="inline_table"><tr><td>kk1</td></tr></table>
<table class="inline_table"><tr><td>kk2</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
{
  display: block;
  height: 1%;
}
```

Try this.