# Dropdown CSS and HTML Navigation Menu doesn't work in IE6 - IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, nav

I have created a CSS and HTML navigation menu that works in all browsers except IE6 - IE8. How can I make this work? I've attempted to make my css and html as small as possible to help with the compatibility but to no avail.

CSS and HTML

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover > ul {

  display: block;
}
ul {
  background-color: #99CCFF; 
  background-color: rgb(153, 204, 255);
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
}
ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  display:none;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #6699CC;
}
ul li:hover a {
  color: #000000;
}
ul li a {
  display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #000000; text-decoration: none;
}
ul ul {
  background: #99CCFF; padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
ul ul li {
  display:inline;
  float: none; 
  border-top: 0px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #000000; 
} 
ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #6699CC;
}
ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;

}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="address.html">Address</a></li>
      <li><a href="rentals.html">Rentals</a></li>
      <li><a href="phonenumbers.html">Phone Numbers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Mass</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.usccb.org/nab/today.shtml" target="_blank">Readings</a></li>
      <li><a href="bulletins.html">Bulletins</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/ccc_toc.htm"  target="_blank">Catechism</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.archindy.org/" target="_blank">Archdiocese of<br>Indiana</a></li>
      <li><a href="confessions.html">Confession</a></li>
      <li><a href="dailymass.html">Mass Schedule</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Ministries</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="school.html">Pre-School</a></li>
      <li><a href="daycare.html">Day Care</a></li>
      <li><a href="ccd.html">CCD</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.gandouministry.com/" target="_blank">Haiti<br>Ministry</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Info</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="park.html">Walking<br>Park</a></li>
      <li><a href="councils.html">Councils &<br>Committees</a></li>
      <li><a href="cemetery.html">Cemetery Rules</a></li>
      <li><a href="bulletins.html">Bulletins</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/ccc_toc.htm"  target="_blank">Catechism</a></li>
    </ul>
  <li><a href="#">Activities</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="laborday.html">Labor Day<br>Festival</a></li>
      <li><a href="bingo.html">Bingo</a></li>
      <li><a href="drawdon.html">Drawdown</a></li>
      <li><a href="fund.html">MSGR Schmitz<br>Memorial Fund</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, first of all, `>` [*isn't* supported by IE6](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2) I'd suggest dropping support for them. If you really care about IE users, don't make a pure CSS dropdown menu. You would need JS.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't even work in any browser... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/p7BG6/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have too many preceding **ul** selectors in your css rules.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul> </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

That is your basic structure. Try removing the extra **ul** from the css where there are more than 2 of them.

Second, I notice you're using an **inline-table** rule. Rules like these are often trouble with older versions of IE, so make sure to do a compatibility check on these types of rules. Here's another SO post as a reference to this:

[display:inline-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688359/displayinline-table)