# space from top side of cell needed

Tags: html, css, tags, margin, paragraph

I have a text (title and paragraph) in a cell. Using css style I controled it's appereance to look the way I want. 
Now the only thing remains it's for the Title to have just a little space from the top.
Since the Title has the tag L1 that I made I tried using margin parameter but it didn't work.
What's the solution on this?

CSS

```
<style>
p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
L1{
    font-size:12px}
</style>
```

And the cell code is :

```
<td width="373" valign="top"><p><strong><l1>ARTICLE #11</l1></strong><p>          
<br>          
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis elit in lobortis interdum. Morbi gravida scelerisque ultrices. Suspendisse eget felis efficitur, porttitor tellus eget, euismod metus. Nullam id pellentesque quam, quis ultrices ipsum. Aenean orci purus, ultrices vel</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the l1 tag to some other tag like span and add css display block it will work then

Comment: I created the L1 cuz it was necessary so I can give to my title some characteristics. I did changed it to span though and it didn't work.

Comment: What you think? it that ok? Will this work in most browsers?
http://jsfiddle.net/mdermez32/mxyxj8kp/

Comment: yes this will work in all the browsers http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/mxyxj8kp/1/

Comment: You think block it's better than inline table (cuz they have the same output but I don't know much).  :)

Comment: because every css property have a meaning you can check it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `<l1>` is not a valid HTML tag.

Changing it to a `<h1>` tag, as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvsf0Lwe/), should do the trick.

```
<h1>ARTICLE #11</h1>
```

Remember to edit the CSS to reflect the change

```
h1{
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `display` to `inline-block` in `h1`(assuming you want h1) element:

```css
p {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font-size:12px;
    display: inline-block;/*change display to inline block*/
    padding-top: 10px;/*Add padding top*/
}

table{
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="373" valign="top">
            <p><strong><h1>ARTICLE #11</l1></strong>

            </p>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis elit in lobortis interdum. Morbi gravida scelerisque ultrices. Suspendisse eget felis efficitur, porttitor tellus eget, euismod metus. Nullam id pellentesque quam, quis ultrices ipsum. Aenean orci purus, ultrices vel</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I kept only the display thing and used marging instead of padding. 
It seems to work. Should I type the rest ? (table border)

Comment: No of course. Just add it to see the result in a better way. You just need `display-inline: block` and `padding` or `margin`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mdermez32/mxyxj8kp/
Chech this one. It seems that inline block or table have the same output. Isn't that correct? Which one should I use then?

Comment: Your jsfiddle is incorrect. `td` should be child of tr element and tr elements child of table element. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/mxyxj8kp/5/

Comment: you do realize that this is an excerpt? :)  it's not incorrect it's just incomplete in purpose so I can type less. Beside that is everything else right?

Comment: Yes, just change` margin-top` according to your needs:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-table;` it works

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/mcxw1pn8/

Comment: I added     display:inline-table and changed a few numbers. I get a green underline on "inline-table" (like when you type something wrong).. Should I ignore this? Its seems to work though.

Comment: green underline? give me a jsfiddle to check.

Comment: i thinks display is not responsible for that

Comment: What you think? it that ok? Will this work in most browsers?
http://jsfiddle.net/mdermez32/mxyxj8kp/

Comment: Yes it works look a this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688359/displayinline-table .

Comment: I don't have enough reputation (new account) I will do so a soon as I get my reputation up. :)